# Highlighting point in all datasets on hover over

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I have something similar to the Chart Js sample [here](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/positioning.html) where I have multiple datasets in my chart that I set as 'index.' When you hover over a point, each dataset's point matching that x-value will highlight. Is there any way to set that highlighting to work the same way as the tooltip? I want to have the points highlight when the mouse hovers over the x-axis, not just the points.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`options.hover.intersect`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/?h=intersect):

> if true, the hover mode only applies when the mouse position intersects an item on the chart.

The default is `true` so you should change it to `false`:

```
options: {
    hover: {
        intersect: false
    }
}
```

Comment: @GetOtterHere Did this answer your question?